# C++ variable issue

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>                                               
#include <cstring>                                              
#include <cmath>                                                
#include <iomanip>                                              
#include <fstream>                                              
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>                                              
#include <ctime>                                                
#include <cctype>           

using namespace  std;


void printA(int i, int a, int setA[]);
void printB(int i, int b, int setB[]);
int printUnion(int setA[], int setB[], int setUnion[], int a, int b);
void sort(int array[], int x);
int printIntersection(int setA[], int setB[], int setIntersection[], int a, int b, int k);

 int main()
{
ifstream infile;                                                //Input file
ofstream outfile;
infile.open("c:\\Temp\\setsA.dat");                             //checks for file validity
if (!infile)
{
    cout<<"Cannot open the input file."
        <<"This program will end."<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}




cout<<"This program will compute the set cardinality."<<endl;
cout<<"Select from the following option: "<<endl;
cout<<"1 Compute and Output Set A Cardinality"<<endl;
cout<<"2 Compute and Output Set B Cardinality"<<endl;
cout<<"3 Compute and Output Cardinality of A's union with B"<<endl;
cout<<"4 Quit"<<endl;

int setA[30];
int setB[30];
int setUnion[30];
int setIntersection[30];
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
while (!infile.eof())
    {           
        infile>>setA[a];
        if(infile.eof())
            break;
        a++;                
    }
infile.close();
sort(setA, a);

infile.open("C:\\Temp\\setsB.dat");
if (!infile)
{
    cout<<"Cannot open the input file."
    <<"This program will end."<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}

while (!infile.eof())
    {           
        infile>>setB[b];
        if(infile.eof())
            break;
        b++;                
    }
sort(setB, b);
infile.close();


outfile.open("c:\\Temp\\outset.dat", ios::app);
int option;
cin>>option;
while(option!=4)
{
    if (option == 1)
    {
        printA(i, a, setA);
        outfile<<"Cardinality of Set A is "<<a<<endl;
    }

    else if (option == 2)
    {
        printB(i, b, setB);
        outfile<<"Cardinality of Set B is "<<b<<endl;
    }

    else if (option == 3)
    {
        printUnion(setA, setB, setUnion, a, b);
        printIntersection(setA,setB,setIntersection,a,b,k);
        outfile<<"Cardinality of Set A's union with Set B is "<<a+b-k<<endl;
    }

        cin>>option;
}


outfile.close();


system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}


 void printA(int i, int a, int setA[])
 {
cout<<"Set A : {";
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    if(i > 0)
        cout<<",";
        cout<<setA[i];          
}
cout<<"}"<<endl;
cout<<"Cardinality of set A is "<<a<<endl;

 }

 void printB(int i, int b, int setB[])
 {
cout<<"Set B : {";
for(i=0;i<b;i++)
{
    if(i > 0)
        cout<<",";
        cout<<setB[i];      
}
cout<<"}"<<endl;
cout<<"Cardinality of set B is "<<b<<endl;
 }

 int printUnion(int setA[], int setB[], int setUnion[], int a, int b)
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int u = 0;
while ((i < a) && (j < b))
{
    if (setA[i] < setB[j])
    {
        setUnion[u] = setA[i];
        i++;
        u++;
    }

    else if (setA[i] > setB[j])
    {
        setUnion[u] = setB[j];
        j++;
        u++;
    }

    else
    {
        setUnion[u] = setA[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        u++;
    }
}

if (i == a)
{
    while (j < b)
    {
        setUnion[u] = setB[j];
        j++;
        u++;
    }
}

else
{
    while (i < a)
    {
        setUnion[u] = setA[i];
        i++;
        u++;
    }
}
cout<<"Cardinality of union set is "<<u<<endl;
return 0;

}

int printIntersection(int setA[], int setB[], int setIntersection[], int a, int b, int k) {
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;

 while(i < a && j < b)
 {
     if(setA[i] < setB[j])
     {
         i++;
     }

     else if(setA[i] > setB[j])
     {
         j++;
     }

     else if (setA[i] == setB[j])
     {
         setIntersection[k] = setA[i];
         i++;
         j++;
         k++;
     }       
 }
        cout<<"Cardinality of intersection is "<<k<<endl;
        return 0;
 }

void sort(int array[], int x)

{
 int i, j, temp, swapping;
for (i = 1; i < x; i++)

{
    swapping = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < x-i; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j+1])
        {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
            swapping = 1;
        }
    }

    if (swapping == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code for my program. I've to print the cardinality of individual sets and the union of two sets. In my function printIntersection I'm setting "k" as the variable to hold the cardinality of the intersection set. When I call k in main under switch statement case 3, it is still 0. I think it is fetching the k from main and not the function printIntersection. How would I set and use "k" in switch statement so that it would give me correct value ?

Comment: `k` is a local variable both in `main()` and in the other function. They just happen to have the same name, but are otherwise completely unrelated... you may want to look at pointers and/or references if you want to do what you say.

Comment: is this long code really relevant to your question? can you just pick out only relevant , may be a bit shorter code?

Comment: The variable k within main is only assigned to zero.  It never is changed thereafter.  As is pointed out below, if you want the `printIntersection` function, where k is passed by value, to update the k declared within main, then modify the `printIntersection` method as @user3434680 described in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that "k" is not being updated is because you are passing it by value.  Any changes made to "k" in your function are lost after the function exits.

If you change

```
int printIntersection(int setA[], int setB[], int setIntersection[], int a, int b, int k) {
```

To

```
int printIntersection(int setA[], int setB[], int setIntersection[], int a, int b, int &k) {
```

You will now be passing "k" to printIntersection by reference, rather than by value, and your changes will remain, even after the function exits

Comment: Thanks @user3434680. that worked perfectly. and I also moved the declaration of k into  while loop because if the same option was selected every time, the value of k was changing.